# Indefinite integrals with rati0nal and polynomial functions and Substituion

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am totally confused with the substitution method of evaluating indefinite integrals, especially those with rational functions and polynomials. I have 2 cases, which if I made to understand, would break ice for my future cases.

case 1: Evaluate: $\int x\sqrt{x+2}dx $

case 2: Evaluate: $\int \frac{x^3-x^2+5x-5}{x-1} dx $

For case1: I thought it was simple substitution $u=(x+2)$ then having:
$\int x.u^{1/2}dx $

For which I would then integrate $\int x\int u^{1/2}dx $

to get $\frac{x^2}{2}.\frac{2.u^{3/2}}{3}$
...and then I just plug in back my $u$.

Help on these two. Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that $x\sqrt{x+2}$ is not a rational function.

Comment: You definitely are not understanding how substitution works. How did you get a double integral out of a single integral from substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you replace x you've to replace x everywhere. If $u=x+2$ then $x=u-2$ and $dx= du$. This means that your integral become
\begin{equation}
\int (u-2) \sqrt u du = \int u \sqrt{u} du -2 \int \sqrt{u} du=\frac{2}{15}(3u-10) u^{\frac{3}{2}}
\end{equation}
Now you go back by replacing $u$ by $x+2$. For the second integral please note that
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^3-x^2+5x-5}{x-1}=\frac{x^3-x^2}{x-1}+5=\frac{x^2(x-1)}{x-1}+5=x^2+5
\end{equation}
which is easy to integrate

Comment: I appreciate. I got the hint for case2 well. I am still following case 1 keenly with other exams. I am trying to use the method above with another case. It does seem to work. I need to do more practice examples,  like this case: $\int 3x{(2x^2+3)}^5 dx$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for 1:** If $u = x+2$ then $du = dx$ and $x = u-2$. Hence your  first integral becomes $$\int x\sqrt{x+2}dx = \int(u-2)\sqrt{u}\space du$$ Remember this is single variable calculus, so it doesn't make sense to evaluate an integral like $\int x\sqrt{u}\space dx$ where both $x$ and $u$ are variables; the integral needs to be cast *completely* in terms of one variable.

**Hint for 2:** Any time you are trying to integrate a ratio of polynomials, and the polynomial in the numerator has a higher degree than the one in the denominator, try polynomial division.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exactly the same method. For instance use the substitution $2 x^2+3=u$. With this substitution you have
\begin{equation}
2 x dx = \frac{1}{2} du
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
 x dx = \frac{1}{4} du
\end{equation}
Then your integral becomes:
\begin{equation}
\int 3 u^5 \frac{1}{4} du =\frac{u^6}{8}
\end{equation}
Now you replace u by $2 x^2+3$, and you get the result.